# Hyper-V on one machine

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, windows, hyper-v-server-2012

**Context:**
We have one machine `Intel Xeon X3440 @ 2.53GHz; 8 GB RAM` on which we would like to run windows and linux installations. We have decided to go with Hyper-V since we are mainly focused on Microsoft technologies. This machine is supposed to run staging builds of some of our websites and hold our repositories. The linux installation is needed for minority of projects that will run on unix in production.

**Question:**
Is this machine sufficient enough to run `Windows Server 2012` and `Debian wheezy`? If so, should we go for Hyper-V server or Windows Server 2012 with Hyper-V role? Licensing is not an issue, as we are in BizSpark program.

Comment: Personally, I'd install Hyper-V and then Server 2012 in one VM and Wheezy in another. Hyper-V handling of Linux is not as good as VMWare, however.

Comment: Why would you consciously pick a Linux distribution not supported by Hyper-V? It's asking for trouble. Also I'd suggest you'll need more memory.

Answer (score 2):

Noone can answer - you talk about:

> Is this machine sufficient enough to run Windows Server 2012 and Debian wheezy?

But this is not what you care about. You care about those servers also doing work, and how much memory they use depends on what you install in them.

It will likely get tight - I run all my smaller Hyper-V machines with 32gb memory.

Comment: Just how much memory does your phone have?!?

Comment: A lot. But seriously - a Hasswell E3 micro atx goes to 32gb, a AMD G32 micro atx goes to 64gb. And memory is CHEAP. The larger question on such small hyper-v servers is - disc io.